# Filter Java list and create integer constants array

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, int

I have a `Java list of Strings` as below:

***myList:***

```
C26366
C10025, C10026
C10244
C26595
C26594
C9026, C9027, C9029, C9080 //this is one list element (needs seperation)
C26597
C10223, C10287, C10277, C10215
C10242
C10243 
C9025, C9030, C9034, C9051, C9052, C9055 // similarly here
C10241
C10067
C27557
C10066
.... //these are all ids
```

Above is an output of below `for-loop` snippet:

```
for (String id: myList) {
      System.out.println(id);   
}
```

How do I convert this myList into a Java integer array? I am expecting something like/I want to use use that array as:

```
public static final IDS = { 31598,9089,9092,9093,9108,9109,....}
```

`IDS array` must hold the content from `myList` and they are without any `C's` in them and no other characters, but just the numbers.

Comment: Look into `String.split()`, `String.trim()`, and `String.substring()` methods.  Will help solve your problem by splitting on `,` to separate IDs on a line, trimming the white space, and substring to remove the C characters.  String JavaDoc available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to do this:

1. Define a list of integers for the final values
2. then use Regex with this pattern "\d+" to find in the list of strings only the things that are numeric
3. if found, parse it to integer and add it to the list.

---

## Example:

```
List<Integer> myListIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String subStrings : myList) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(subStrings);
    while (m.find()) {
        myListIntegers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
    }
}
System.out.println(myListIntegers);
```

this code will print the list holding the insteger you have in **myList**

> [26366, 10025, 10026, 10244, 26595, 26594, 9026, 9027, 9029, 9080,
>   10241, 10067, 27557, 10066]

Comment: Worked - got the required list. I can take it on from here.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you can use streams:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(
        "C26366", "C10025, C10026", "C10244", "C26595", "C26594",
        "C9026, C9027, C9029, C9080", "C26597", "C10223, C10287, C10277, C10215", 
        "C10242", "C10243",
        "C9025, C9030, C9034, C9051, C9052, C9055", "C10241", "C10067");

List<Integer> myListOfIntegers = myList.stream()
        .map(x -> x.split(","))
        .flatMap(l -> Arrays.asList(l).stream())
        .map(y -> y.replaceAll("\\D", ""))
        .map(z->Integer.parseInt(z))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

for( Integer i : myListOfIntegers ){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

a result is:

```
26366
10025
10026
10244
26595
26594
9026
9027
9029
9080
26597
10223
10287
10277
10215
10242
10243
9025
9030
9034
9051
9052
9055
10241
10067
```

Comment: Wish I could use Java 8, still on Java 7. I will keep this stream() up in mind.